get route of flask app doesn't work in python
i have defined a get route for my data minning project and i do not receive the output .Instead ii receive null as the output or else a 404 errror
#import flask
from http.client import responses
import util
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app =Flask(__name__)
# @app.route('/hello')

def hello():
   return "HI girl"

# we need 2  routings, to return the locations in the file
@app.route('/home')
def home():
     return "welcome to thr home page"

@app.route('/get_location_names', methods=['GET'])
def get_location_names():
    #returned would be jsonify method

    response =jsonify({
        "locations":util.get_location_names()
    })
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*')

    return response
enter image description here

i have defined all the necessary steps
